# Script not working in crontab

Tags: linux, centos

I have a script to start my minecraft server each reboot. I can see in the logs it's calling the cmd, but no screen is being opened. If I work run the script manually `/home/minecraft/scripts/startMinecraft.sh` it works perfectly.

Here's my crontab:

```
@reboot /home/minecraft/scripts/startMinecraft.sh
38 00,06,12,16 * * * /home/minecraft/scripts/backup.sh
```

It's a centos 6 server.

Here's my `startMinecraft.sh` script.

```
screen -A -m -d -S minecraftserver /home/minecraft/scripts/startServer.sh
```

As I said before, if I run that exact line manually, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you need to set the full path for binaries like `screen` since when the cron job runs, it will not have the $PATH values set the same way you as a user have those set when you login via Terminal or SSH. [This answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2409369/117259) is a decent explanation of the whole deal.

So I would recommend you change your script from this:

```
screen -A -m -d -S minecraftserver /home/minecraft/scripts/startServer.sh
```

To this:

```
/path/to/screen -A -m -d -S minecraftserver /home/minecraft/scripts/startServer.sh
```

And replace `/path/to/screen` with the actual full path which you can easily obtain using [`which`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/which) like this:

```
which screen
```

The output would be something like:

```
/usr/bin/screen
```

Or, you could set the $PATH by actually placing it in your script like this:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Of course that should match your actual PATH value on your system which you can get by typing in the following:

```
echo $PATH
```

But I personally prefer the fullpath method since it’s cleaner to me and $PATH values often change so you don’t want to have a wish-mash of values in your Bash scripts.

PS: Also, a small thing but your Bash script should have the actual Bash interpretter value set in the [“shebang”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) at the top like this so your script would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/screen -A -m -d -S minecraftserver /home/minecraft/scripts/startServer.sh
```

Of course that `/bin/bash` should match your systems actual Bash path by running `which bash` but I doubt it would not be in the `/bin/bash` path on a modern install.

Comment: I have changed the startMinecraft script to `#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/screen -A -m -d -S minecraftserver /home/minecraft/scripts/startServer.sh` and unfortunately no change. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: yes I used the `which` command to find out the path, and I just manually ran the script and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I'm sure @JakeGould is in the right area with his advice. Maybe there are other aspects of the environment which `minecraft` itself needs (other variables, `$PATH` entries, other services, etc). You could put the script in the start-up applications executed on log-in, instead of trying to use `crontab` with the `@reboot` line, which I would not recommend for GUI applications. You may need to precede it with `bash -c`.